# Android application does not support 17.3 inch tablet

Tags: android

My application is only for tablets and it supports 10906 devices.

Here is my support-screens

```
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

But it does not support one of tablets which is **TCL_Xess_P17AA_OS**.

Specifications of the device are :

- 17.3-inch (1920 x 1080 pixels)
- 10-point multi-tuch display
- 1.5 GHz Octa-Core MediaTek MT8783T processor
- 2GB RAM, 32GB internal memory, expandable memory with microSD
- Android 5.1 (Lollipop)

Any ideas why my app does not support this device?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not support this device"? Are you referring to a message that you are getting in the Play Store?

Comment: @CommonsWare Play Store doesn't allow to download application and when I check Google Play Developer Console, this device is in unsupported devices.

Comment: Post your entire manifest, except perhaps the contents of the `<application>` tag. For example, what `<uses-permission>` and `<uses-feature>` elements do you have?